# How to get the direction of movement?

Tags: vectors, angle

I am trying to get the ***general*** direction of a moving object. So far my idea is very simple:

`degree = (y_new - y_old) / (x_new - x_old)`

where `y_old` and `x_old` both refer to the x,y coordinates of the center of the object from for example 5 frames before. But this doesn't work and it gives a lot of nan or 0 as the direction of movement. How can I get the degree of the movement vector properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\theta=\text{atan}_2({y_{n}-y_{o}},{x_{n}-x_{o}})$$

The function $\text{atan}_2$ is found in most numerical libraries, and returns radians. See [its definition on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).